# What is the triple factorial of a negative number, e.g., $-2$?

Tags: calculus, factorial

The triple factorial of a positive integer is computed as $7!!! = 7\cdot 4\cdot 1$.

I'm interested in the value of $$(-2)!!!$$

I tried to find this value by using the Wolfram, but I found the Wolfram doesn't support this form.

Comment: How do you define the $!!!$ operation? Do you mean $(((-2)!)!)!$, or something else?

Comment: @Aruther for example 7!!!=7*4*1

Comment: @Power and for negative integer?

Comment: What is the pattern there? How do you go from $6$ to $3$ to $1$?

Comment: http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-19/NNTDM-19-2-30_42.pdf this might be of some use?

Comment: @Arthur sorry I have edited my comment

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Alternative_extension_of_the_multifactorial ?

Comment: @MartinR  but there is nothing about the triple factorial in your reference.

Comment: @Power: $z!^{(k)}$ is the notation for the k-th multifactorial in that article. For $k=3$ you get exactly your triple factorial.

Comment: @Mathsstudent Where I come from, writing a Maths/Physics paper using MS Word and including MS Excel graphs (poorly formatted) is sufficient reason for capital punishment. Just sayin'...

Comment: This is probably the first question here with a title ending in triple exclamation points that I didn't automatically downvote. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "triple factorial" is defined for non-negative integers $n$ as
$$
n!!! = n (n-3)(n-6) \cdots (n \bmod 3) \, ,
$$
compare ["Multifactorials" in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials). For $n \ge 0$ and $j > 0$
$$
n!!! = \frac{(n+3j)!!!}{(n+3)(n+6)\cdots (n+3j)} \tag{1}
$$
holds. This relation can be used to define the function for
negative integers as well, as long as they are not a multiple of $(-3)$:
Just choose $j$ large enough such that $n + 3j\ge 0$.
It is easy to see that the definition does not depend on the actual value
of $j$.

For $n=-2$ we get
$$
 (-2) !!! = \frac {(-2 + 3)!!!}{(-2 + 3)} = \frac {1!!!}{1} = 1 \, .
$$

Actually it can even be extended to all complex numbers except for
the negative integers which are multiple of $(-3)$, and an explicit
formula is given in the referenced Wikipedia article in terms of
the Gamma function (choose $k=3$ in the "Alternative extension of the multifactorial"):
$$
z!!! = 3^{(z-1)/3} \frac{\Gamma(\frac z3 + 1)}{\Gamma(\frac 13 + 1)}
$$

For $z = -2$ this gives the same result
$$
(-2)!!! = 3^{-1}\frac{\Gamma(\frac 13)}{\Gamma(\frac 43)} = 1 \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

The value of $(-2)!!!=1$ according to 
$$n!!!=n(n-3)!!!$$
$$1!!!=1(1-3)!!!$$
$$1=(-2)!!!$$

Comment: The identity used above only works for $n\ge3$

Comment: @k1.M,yes thanks for your comments